# VBA DOM Variable in XPath Attribute

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a program that searches for and gathers (via array) a specific author and their 'BookType' and 'BookTitle' I am now trying to learn how to use the author's name - that I've stored in an array - as a variable in the XPath to get the 'Store Location'. Something like: "/catalog/book/misc/PublisherAuthor id="myvar"/StoreLocation"

Three things that are really confusing me:
1. How would you declare a variable in XPath if it's an array (if possible)?
2. Is it a bad idea to declare a statement like this inside the For loop?
3. Is my XPath/DOM logic correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="5691">
            <PublisherLocation>Los Angeles</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Gambardella, Matthew">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="4787">
            <PublisherLocation>New York</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls, Kim">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Boal, John</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="8101">
            <PublisherLocation>New Mexico</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Boal, John">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Mystery">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="6642">
            <PublisherLocation>New York</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls, Kim">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
</catalog>
```

My code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String, StoreLocation As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As String, StoreLocationArray() As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")


x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
    ReDim Preserve AuthorArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve BookTypeArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve TitleArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve StoreLocationArray(0 To i)

    athr = Author(i).Text
    BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
    Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue
    StoreLocation = Author(i).ParentNode.selectSingleNode("/misc/PublishedAuthor[@id=""&athr(j)&""]/StoreLocation").NodeValue

    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then

        AuthorArray(j) = athr
        BookTypeArray(j) = BookType
        TitleArray(j) = Title
        StoreLocationArray(j) = StoreLocation

        j = j + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next

Range("A3:A" & UBound(AuthorArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3:B" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
Range("C3:C" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)
Range("D3:D" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)
```

To be specific, it's this line that I don't understand how to setup:

```
StoreLocation = Author(i).ParentNode.selectSingleNode("/misc/PublishedAuthor[@id=""&athr(j)&""]/StoreLocation").NodeValue
```

Is doing something like this frowned upon? Is there a more logical way?

Thank you for any guidance, help, or comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double-up quotes to escape them:

```
StoreLocation = Author(i).ParentNode.selectSingleNode( _
   "/misc/PublishedAuthor[@id=""" & athr & """]/StoreLocation").NodeValue
```

EDIT: this worked for me

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String, StoreLocation As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String
Dim TitleArray() As String, StoreLocationArray() As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long, locs

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")

x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")

For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)

    athr = Author(i).Text

    'moved a bunch of your code inside this check...
    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then

        BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
        Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue

        Set locs = Author(i).ParentNode.SelectNodes( _
               "misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & athr & "']/StoreLocation")

        If locs.Length > 0 Then
            StoreLocation = locs(0).nodeTypedValue
        Else
            StoreLocation = "???"
        End If

        ReDim Preserve AuthorArray(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve BookTypeArray(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve TitleArray(0 To j)
        ReDim Preserve StoreLocationArray(0 To j)

        AuthorArray(j) = athr
        BookTypeArray(j) = BookType
        TitleArray(j) = Title
        StoreLocationArray(j) = StoreLocation

        j = j + 1
        x = x + 1

    End If
Next

If j > 0 Then

    Range("A3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
    Range("B3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
    Range("C3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)
    Range("D3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(StoreLocationArray)

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I am getting an `Object variable or With block variable not set`. Do you think it's because I'm trying to go back to the ParentNode and then selectSingleNode?

Comment: Awesome, thanks Tim. `toreLocation = Author(i).ParentNode.selectSingleNode("/misc/PublishedAuthor[@id=""&athr(j)&""]/StoreLocation").Text` also fixed the object error (Text as opposed to NodeValue)

Comment: If you're interested, I ran into a similar scenario that I can't figure out (what if only the author's last name is shown?). I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639301/vba-dom-variable-attribute-in-xpath. Appreciate your kindness and help!